# Updating a row in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-connection, database-administration

I need to update a couple of rows in my database. But after updating the values and having confirmation that the values were updated, it reverts back to its original values.

Here is the script that I wrote

```
BEGIN TRAN;

UPDATE cars
SET sold = sold + 5
WHERE id IN (18, 25);

COMMIT TRAN;
```

I ran the above script successfully, no errors were displayed and it showed that 2 rows were updated. I ran `SELECT` on the cars table and it showed that sold was indeed updated.

After that, I went and opened the system (a custom system for my project) that is using this database to view it on my admin panel. However, the sold column was not updated and showed the old values. When I ran `SELECT` again on the cars table, it returns my old values instead of the updated one.

Am I doing anything wrong? Since I have ran `SELECT` after updating and it showed that the values were indeed updated.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are inserting into the same database as your app is running against?

Comment: Yes I am 100% positively sure.

Comment: How does your app connect to the DB? Does it use EF or similar?

Comment: I'll suggest to run the SQL Profiler to see how it's reverting back

Comment: Can you please show us the **connection string** for SQL Server that you're using? I'm almost sure you have something like `AttachDbFileName=......` in there somewhere......

Comment: please post the app code. It may be caching the values and reverting them back.

Answer (score 0):

begin try

BEGIN TRAN;
UPDATE cars
SET sold = sold + 5
WHERE id IN (18, 25) and isnumeric(sold)=1

> isnumeric fileters only numerics bcz your trying add numeric values it does't meets casting problems

COMMIT TRAN;

> Commits if it is ok

end try
begin catch

rollback

> rollbacks the transaction if any exception occured.

end catch

Answer (score 0):

Another operation is updating the table again. Use the SQL SERVER PROFILER and check if other transactions are executed after your UPDATE. Additionally, in your project verify by sending the correct parameters so that you return the result you expect.